# Extending a placeholder and a regular class

Tags: sass

I'm having a little issue with SASS @extend, placeholder class and interpolation.

I'm trying to keep the HTML as clean as possible and that's I decided to go for the @extend function in pair with placeholder classes. However, I'm mainly extending layout-related classes like grid, list etc - that's why I'm mixing a placeholder with a regular class in the declaration, i.e:

```
%drawer,
.drawer {
 ...
}
```

Everything was going just fine except for a moment when I noticed the interpolation with the variable being the ampersand in the main class causes some issues. Sample code (with most of the CSS rules removed):

```
%drawer,
.drawer {
  $this: &;

  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;

  &__content {
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }

  &__optional-element {
    background: red;
  }

  &--left { // I want this modifier to be applied to the parent element as it may affect more than one children element
    #{$this}__content {
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

And the extension code:

```
.product-drawer {
  @extend %drawer;

  &__content {
    @extend %drawer__content;
  }
}
```

However, the compiled CSS output is the following:

```
.drawer--left .product-drawer,
.drawer--left .drawer__content {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

You may notice the first line is redundant and actually wrong. In addition, the "&__optional-element" bit is not outputted for the "product-drawer" extension which makes it really strange. It happens only to rules with the $this interpolation.

As soon as I remove the regular ".drawer" class from the original declaration (and just leave %drawer there), the problem is gone but in these layout-related classes (.grid, .list), we want to keep the regular class name as well so in some various, simple cases it can be used as well, without a need to write new CSS and extending it the placeholder class.

I know that this could be resolved by separating the placeholder class (%drawer) from the regular one (.drawer) completely and then extend the placeholder class inside the regular ".drawer" declaration but that would simply duplicate the code... Or maybe my approach is wrong by design?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `@extend` rule. The thing is that placeholders are a shallow copy of a class. If you extend from a class you are going to inherit all its properties, but if you extend from a placeholder it is only going to copy the first level.

See this example:

```
%placeholder{
  content: 'placeholder';
  &__element{
    content: 'placeholder__element';
  }
}

.a{
  @extend %placeholder;
}

.class{
  content: 'class';
  &__element{
    content: 'class__element';
  }
}

.b{
  @extend .class;
}
```

```
.a {
  content: 'placeholder';
}

.class, .b {
  content: 'class';
}

.class__element {
  content: 'class__element';
}
```

By using both you're forcing placeholder class to use also the properties:

```
 %placeholder,
.class{
  content: 'class';
  &__element{
    content: 'class__element';
  }
}

.b{
  @extend %placeholder;
}
```

```
.b,
.class {
  content: 'class';
}


.class__element {
  content: 'class__element';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your second example is something I'm perfectly aware of and that's the desired result I'm expecting. The issue is related to the interpolation of the ampersand that is stored in the "$this" variable. It's the specific example I posted in my original message.